# Sinatra: Undefined method 'run' when using bundle exec ruby app.rb

Tags: ruby, sinatra, bundler

I have modular style sinatra app, with the following line near the end, so that it can be run standalone:

```
  # ... all code before this omitted
  run! if __FILE__ == $0

end
# This is the end of the file
```

When I run this app with `ruby app.rb` it works fine, and webrick starts up.

However, if I run it instead with `bundle exec ruby app.rb` I get this error:

```
>bundle exec ruby app.rb
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1488:in `start_server': undefined method `run' for HTTP:Module (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1426:in `run!'
```

What's causing this error?

Comment: Hi Arup, please read the first line of the OP again: I am using the modular approach.  There should be nothing else relevant in the stripped out code.

Comment: Sorry - That I missed how I don't know. But *undefined method 'run' for HTTP:Module (NoMethodError)*.. is telling you are calling it inside the module called `HTTP`... So Need to check, why are you calling it from there.. ? Have you [checked](http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/#automatic_code_reloading) this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explicitly set your webserver, e.g.

```
set :server, 'thin'
```

and make sure you add whatever server you’re using to your `Gemfile`, e.g.

```
gem 'thin'
```

Comment: Interesting.. How do you come to know, this causes the issue ? I am asking out of curiosity...

Comment: @ArupRakshit I’ve seen this before, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118533/sinatra-does-not-start-with-twitter-gem/22123292#22123292 for an example (there are other similar questions around too). I’ve actually got a patch for Rack that should fix this, I should tidy it up and send a PR.